# Complex data select from the store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

My store:

```
{
  entities: {
    posts: {
      6: {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Some title',
        account_id: 2,
        ...
      }
    }
    comments: {
      1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Some name',
        ...
      }
    }
    accounts: {
      1: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Antonio',
        ...
      }
    }
  }
  pagination: {
    // Comments by POST ID
    comments: {
      6: {
        ids: [1,2, ..., 6],
        isFetching: false,
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For every post page i have a comments sections, where i display all the comments. Comment component includes author `username` and the comment details. Comments and authors stored separately in the store as entities (`comments`, `accounts`) and connected only by **FK** (`account_id`). What i need is to display all the comments for the post including author information (`username`).

So, i decided to create 2 (`reselect`) selectors for that:

```
const getComments = state => state.entities.comments;
const getCommentIds = (state, props) => {
  const id = props.match.params.post;
  const comments = state.pagination.comments[id];

  return (comments && !comments.isFetching) ? comments.ids : [];
}
const getUsers = state => state.entities.accounts;

export const getPostComments = createSelector(
  [ getComments, getCommentIds ], (comments, ids) => {
    return ids.map(id => comments[id]);
  }
)

export const getCommentsWithAuthors = createSelector(
  [ getPostComments, getUsers ], (comments, users) => {
    return comments.map(comment => {
      const { username } = users[comment.account_id];

      return Object.assign({}, comment, { username });
    });
  }
)
```

**mapStateToProps** function:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  const id = props.match.params.post;
  const { posts } = state.entities;

  return {
    post: state.entities.posts[id],
    comments: getCommentsWithAuthors(state, props)
  }
}
```

Everything is working fine, but i'm wondering if this is the common approach or maybe the architecture of my `state` object is poor and that is why i'm encountering with such a solution ?

Comment: Your solution is pretty much spot on with how a lot of people do it, Here's a disection of Twitter's redux store that is similar in structure to yours: https://medium.com/statuscode/dissecting-twitters-redux-store-d7280b62c6b1. Reselect was created for exactly this use case.

Comment: @JoeRuello thanks, I’ll definitely look into that post. Basically, that means that my implementation is ok?

Comment: Also you can check - [How to deal with relational data in Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45373369/4312466)