# Accessing a List of Objects when your State is Normalized / Flat

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Redux recommends your state be flat per here: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape

So say my state was like this:

```
{
    selectedPlaylistIndex: 0,
    pageDict: {},
    playlistDict: {},
    playlistList: []  // holds IDs from playlistDict
}
```

a sample Playlist Object would look like:

```
{
    id: someId,
    active: false,
    pageList: [], // holds IDs from pageDict
}
```

If I want to state create a Container for displaying the "pageList" of a Playlist object, I pass in the Playlists' "pageList" property as a list of the full Page objects (as opposed to the IDs).  I feel like it's an expensive operation as anytime pageDict, playlistDict, playlistList, or selectedPlaylistIndex get updated, it will be rendered and the function will run.

Is there a more elegant / better way of doing this?  I feel like I'm missing something.

```
// Expensive Operation; Want to Find Better Solution?
    getSelectedPlaylistPageObjArr() {
        const { selectedPlaylistIndex, pageDict, playlistDict, playlistList } = this.props;
        return playlistDict[ playlistList[ selectedPlaylistIndex ]].pageList.map( id => pageDict[id] ) : [];
      }

  render() {
    return (
      <Playlist
        pageObjArr={this.getSelectedPlaylistPageObjArr()}
      />
    );
  }


const mapStateToProps = ( state ) => {
  return {
    pageDict: state.entities.pageDict,
    playlistDict: state.entities.playlistDict,
    playlistList: state.entities.playlistList,
    selectedPlaylistIndex: state.application.selectedPlaylistIndex,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalising, you're asking *how to handle relational data*.

Last time I had to deal with relational data I integrated [redux-orm](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm) library. It's a small and immutable ORM to manage relational data in your Redux store.

So let's say your business logic is as follows *1 Playlist has many Pages*, then in order to get the Pages of the selected Playlist (by playlist's id), it would be computed with `redux-orm`  as follow:

```
const getSelectedPlaylistId = state => state.application.selectedPlaylistIndex

const getPlaylistPages = createSelector(
    orm,
    getSelectedPlaylistId,
    ({ Playlist }, playlistId) => {
        return Playlist.withId(playlistId).Pages.all().toRefArray();
    }
);
```

Once you invoked `getPlaylistPages` the result will be cached and recalculated only when one of the accessed models are changed.

Also if you don't want to use `redux-orm` (let's assume your app doesn't have a lot of models or any other reason), then you can just use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) library, that will cache your performance cost computations.

As I already mention I had such an experience, and my thoughts and conclusions are summarized in the following SO question: [How to deal with relational data in Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45373369/4312466)

Comment: thank you i really appreciate you responding to this.  i'm going to start doing my research into everything you linked right now.  thank you